# DShow source filter: which instance of filter am I?

Tags: video, camera, directshow, capture, source-filter

I have a custom source filter, made by implementing `CSource` and `CSourceStream` from the dshow baseclasses. It is exported multiple times using the `IFilterMapper2::RegisterFilter` method, under different names. 
Now, in my filter I'd like to know (as soon as possible) which registered instance of the filter it is that is being opened.
For example, suppose I have a dll that emulates a virtual webcam. The same dll exports two instances of the filter, so that in (say) Skype I can select *virtual cam #1* and *virtual cam #2*. In the constructor of either my `CSource` or `CSourceStream` I'd like to know whether it is *virtual cam #1* or *virtual cam #2* that is being constructed. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documented way, but there is a workaround. Since DirectShow is stable it should be working nicely.

In your filter class override `IPersistPropertyBag::Load` and the reads that you do with provided `IPropertyBag::Read` map to registry read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes...\CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory\Instance\<your-instance>`. So you can put all identification you need right there and have it accessible.

Note this is called from application's `BindToObject` call.

[image: Call Stack]

I am doing this in virtual video input backed by IP cameras http://alax.info/blog/1233

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sounds perfect. I'm having some difficulty implementing this, though. My CSource implementing class now inherits from IPersistPropertyBag, but in my CVCam::QueryInterface I notice that the IPersistPropertyBag interface is never requested. IPersistPropertyBag's methods are thus never called. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What I can think of is that you are not indicating support for IPersistPropertyBag (in `GetInterface`).

Comment: If you mean QueryInterface, I am. The `REFIID riid` parameter never equals `IID_IPersistPropertyBag`, either on my `CSource`, my `CSourceStream` on both the `QueryInterface` and `NonDelegatingQueryInterface` methods.

Comment: I didn't check correctly, I had to use the NonDelegatingQueryInterface method on the CSource derived class :)

Comment: Yes, excellent! I found some sample code implementing this same trick here: [link](http://www.sworks.com/keng/da/multimedia/dshow/src/vidcap/vidcap.cpp). Thanks again!